# Find distributions in histogram

Tags: python, histogram

In the below histogram (which I understand is multimodal), how do I find the two distributions using python. I should retain the distribution with maximum mode, ie, I should remove values beyound X>325

[image]

Comment: Before you can write a program you have to address the math problem.  Whet you are showing us isn't two distributions, it's one distribution.  You want to decompose it into two Gaussian distributions, which is a certainly possible.  But how?  Are they added together?  Convoluted?  Do they have the same width?  Do they have the same height?  It's pretty clear that two Gaussian distributions aren't going to be a very good description of the data set.  Does that bother you?

Comment: Out of the two, the distribution ranging from X>325, is caused due to noise in the dataset. I am trying to remove it

Comment: I guess I don't understand.  Why don't you simply remove all the points for which x>325?  That would remove the points that you consider to be noise.  But I wouldn't call it "finding" the two distributions.  It's just eyeballing the data and deciding where to draw the line.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a [Gaussian Mixture Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model#Gaussian_mixture_model). I don't think there is a function in SciPy, but there is one in [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/mixture.html)

[Here](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/05.12-gaussian-mixtures.html) is a tutorial on this.